# how to send JavaScript string from view to controller?

Tags: c#, session

I'm doing a project in visual studio mvc4 c# trying to send a string from a JavaScript function in a View to a controller. I tried to use the Session Object like this:

in the View:

```
  Session["matStr"] = matrixString;
```

in the Controller:

```
  var s = (string)Session["matStr"];
```

but when I get to the controller the Session returns me null.

so I'll be glad to know the answer how to send a JS' string from view to controller thank in advance..

Comment: I add an answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to call a controller Action

```
    $('#btnSendData').click(function() {
            //Send batch to the server  
                $.ajax({    
                        type: 'POST',  
                        url: '@Url.Action("SessionUpdate")',
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 
                        data: JSON.stringify(sessionvalue),    
                        success: function(result) {
                            alert(result);
                        }
                    });
                return false;
            });
```

Here SessionUpdate is a conroller action and you can set the session value as sent in sessionvalue variable and can get the result.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and I'm sorry for my ignorance but how do i pull out the result in the controller?

Comment: and also, I created a button like this:   
<input id="submitBtn2" name="submitBtn2" type="submit" value="save"  />
       and in the function, I changed the #btnSendData to be #submitBtn2 and all the other fields as well but when I click the button nothing happens..

Answer (score 0):

use input hidden field

```
<input type="hidden" id="hid1" runat="server"/>

$("#hid1").val("the val from client to server");
```

then get the value in server side.
i hope that thats what you need.(use the string in server side).

you can also just use some span to set the string in controller

Answer (score 0):

You need to include a `name` for the input. This is what MVC uses to communicate with the View and controller for POSTS.

```
<input type="hidden" id="hid1" name="hid1"/>

$("#hid1").val("string");
```

Then on your controller action you use it as a parameter.

```
public ActionResult Index(string hid1)
{
    return View()
}
```